# How to differentiate between whether a notification is a local or remote notification when app Starts in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

Previously i used the following code to differentiation whether my notification is local or remote when the app starts

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
    [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if (launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.localNotification] != nil)
    {


    }
    if (launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil)
    {


    }
    }
```

The conditions is that my app is killed and I am opening it from notification.

The problem is that this method

```
if (launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.localNotification] != nil)
{


}
```

is deprecated and the following method isnot called when the app is opened from notification center

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the notification type in `userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:` too,

Class hierarchy is:

> `UNNotificationResponse` > `UNNotification` > `UNNotificationRequest` > `UNNotificationTrigger`

**There are 4 types of triggers in `UNNotificationRequest`:**

- `UNLocationNotificationTrigger`
- `UNPushNotificationTrigger`
- `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`
- `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`

Just use,

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if response.notification.request.trigger is UNPushNotificationTrigger {
        print("remote notification");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats works only when app is foreground or background state. It does-not work when the app is killed for local notification case

Answer (score 1):

While creating localnotification set the identifier in the notification which can be used for identifying the difference in the handling notification

> Following is example creating localnotification with identifier.

```
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Title"
        content.body = "Body"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "TestIdentifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

> Handling local notification with identifier.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if response.notification.request.identifier == "TestIdentifier" {
        print("handling notifications with the TestIdentifier Identifier")
    }

    completionHandler()

}
```

> **For Handling remote notification you can use the following line**

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("handling notification")
    if let notification = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String:AnyObject] {
        let message = parseRemoteNotification(notification: notification)
        print(message as Any)
    }
    completionHandler()
}
 
private func parseRemoteNotification(notification:[String:AnyObject]) -> String? {
    if let aps = notification["aps"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
        let alert = aps["alert"] as? String
        return alert
    }
 
    return nil
}
```

> **You can add an additional condition for handling both the notification in the same method by checking identifier in the first
>   line.**

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("handling notification")
 if response.notification.request.identifier == "TestIdentifier" {
        print("handling notifications with the TestIdentifier Identifier")
    }else {
    if let notification = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String:AnyObject] {
        let message = parseRemoteNotification(notification: notification)
        print(message as Any)
    }
}
    completionHandler()
}
 
private func parseRemoteNotification(notification:[String:AnyObject]) -> String? {
    if let aps = notification["aps"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
        let alert = aps["alert"] as? String
        return alert
    }
 
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your local notifications key values in content.userInfo.

```
content.userInfo = ["isMyLocationNotification" : true] //you can set anything
```

Then check in didReceive response method of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo) //you can check your notification types
        }
```

In output section you will user Information data with isMyLocationNotification key, Now you can identify weather notification is local of remote.